# Vue multiple pages with a webworker

Tags: vue.js

Using vue cli 3 I have a project using harp.gl where I need a webworker to decode map tiles.
My vue.config.js has the following:

```
module.exports = {
    pages: {
        app: {
            entry: './src/main.js',
            filename: 'index.html',
            title: 'Contextual Map HARP.GL/Vue',
        },
        decoder: {
            target: "webworker",
            entry: "./src/decoder.js",
            output: {
                filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            },
            devtool: 'source-map',
...
```

When I run this I have both the app and the decode.js running as a webworker of type "script" (when inspecting it using Chrome).

However, after upgrading to vue cli 4 the above code does not work, as inspecting it using Chrome the webworker type is text/html and it appears to serve the default index.html. It alomst as if the type: "webworker" is not working the same as with version 3.

I am at loss as how to fix this, the move from vue cli 3 to 4 changed something, but I cannot figure out what to change.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that config. Can you share a link to a GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem?